# RegEx to match if the string contains 1 or more sets of 1-10 alphanumerics

Tags: regex

RegEx to match if the string contains 1 or more sets of 1-10 alphanumerics (separated by 1 space)

Right now i have this and that will match the alphanumeric part.

```
var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Zs]+$/;
```

After it matches i plan to just use

```
var matches = thetext.Split(' ');
```

to get the various matches.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yeah, but i want to just validate in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `s` in your regular expression instead of `\s` (meaning whitespace).

If you want to enforce that there is exactly one space character (not multiple spaces and not tabs or other whitespace characters) then you can use this:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z]{1,10}(?: [0-9A-Za-z]{1,10})*$/
```

If you also want to allow underscores, you can use `\w` to make the expression more concise:

```
/^\w{1,10}(?: \w{1,10})*$/
```

Comment: (unless he is strict about the "seperated by *one* space" rule)

Comment: correct. the rule is 1-10 alphanumerics any number of times each must have 1 space between them

Comment: this is perfect. would ?:/s convert it to any whitespace between?

Comment: @Eluvitar: Yes, `\s` in Javascript is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]` ([source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)).

Answer (score 1):

Try regexp like this if you don't expact space at begin and spaces should be longer than 1 character

```
var regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Zs]+\s*)*$/;
```

With possible space at begin you can use

```
var regex = /^\s*([0-9a-zA-Zs]+\s*)*$/;
```

If you expact exactly one space and no spaces at begin or end then use

```
var regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Zs]+\s)*[0-9a-zA-Zs]+$/;
```